# PHP - Windows background commands working but still waiting on background process to finish

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, background, pclose

I have tried NUMEROUS methods to start a background php script from another php script. I need to create a zip file of database files for download. I have it set up to download instantly for single files, but if the files need to be zipped, I want a background process to start that will email a link to the zip file. The process works but the original script still waits for the process to finish. I have tried the following methods, and like I said, they work, but they will not go to the background. It had me waiting for over eight minutes for certain instances(large file zips), and no user will wait for that.

```
print `php -f zipfiles7.php | at now`;

$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe -f C:/wamp/www/zipfiles7.php", 0, false);

$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("cmd /c C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe -f C:/wamp/www/zipfiles7.php", 3, false);

$exe = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe";
$args = "C:\wamp\www\zipfiles7.php";
pclose(popen("start \"bla\" \"" . $exe . "\" " . escapeshellarg($args), "r"));

$cmd = "php-win.exe zipfiles7.php";
$cmd = "start /B php-win.exe zipfiles7.php";
$PID = shell_exec("nohup $cmd > test.txt 2>&1");

exec("Psexec.exe -i -d  php.exe zipfiles7.php");

$cmd = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php-win.exe -f C:\wamp\www\zipfiles7.php";
function _exec($cmd)
{
    $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
    $oExec = $WshShell->Run($cmd, 0,false);
    echo $cmd;
    return $oExec == 0 ? true : false;
}_exec("C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php-win.exe -f C:\wamp\www\zipfiles7.php");

$cmd = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php-win.exe -f C:\wamp\www\zipfiles7.php";
pclose(popen('start /B ' . $cmd, 'r'));

$cmd = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php-win.exe -f C:\wamp\www\zipfiles7.php";
pclose(popen("start /B " . $cmd, "r"));

system("cmd /c php zipfiles7.php > test.txt 2>&1");

exec('psexec start /B -d php.exe zipfiles7.php > test.txt 2>&1');

exec('psexec -d php.exe zipfiles7.php > test.txt 2>&1');

exec('psexec -d php.exe zipfiles7.php');

$cmd = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php-win.exe -f C:\wamp\www\zipfiles7.php";
exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, "test.txt", "php_error.log"));

pclose(popen('start /B php zipfiles7.php > test.txt 2>&1', 'r'));

pclose(popen("start /B C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php-win.exe -f C:\wamp\www\zipfiles7.php", "r"));

shell_exec('start /B "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe -f C:\wamp\www\zipfiles7.php > test.txt 2>&1"');

exec('START /B "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe -f C:\wamp\www\zipfiles7.php"', $output);

passthru("start /B c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/php-win c:/wamp/www/zipfiles7.php > test.txt 2>&1");

exec("php.exe -f zipfiles7.php > test.txt 2>&1");

exec("php-win -f zipfiles7.php > /dell/null 2>/dev/null &", $output);

exec("start /B php zipfiles7.php > test.txt 2>&1");

exec("start php.exe -f zipfiles7.php > test.txt 2>&1");

$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("cmd /C C:\wamp\www\batch.bat", 0, false);

exec("CHP.exe C:\wamp\www\batch.bat > test.txt 2>&1");

exec("start /min php zipfiles7.php > test.txt 2>&1");

shell_exec('call "cmd /c batch.bat"');
```

batch.bat

```
@echo off 
"start /B bg C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe -f C:\wamp\www\zipfiles7.php > test.txt"
```

Additional methods tried:

```
$descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
        2 => array("pipe", "r") // stderr is a file to write to
    );

    $cmd = "start /B php.exe zipfiles7.php";
    $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, null);
    if (is_resource($process))
    { ....

// buffer all upcoming output
ob_start();
// get the size of the output
$size = ob_get_length();

// send headers to tell the browser to close the connection
header("Content-Length: $size");
header('Connection: close');

// flush all output
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();

// close current session
if (session_id()) session_write_close();
    exec("start /B php zipfiles7.php > test.txt 2>&1");
```

or

```
shell_exec('psexec -s -d php.exe zipfiles7.php');
```

or

```
$runCommand = 'php -q zipfiles7.php';
    $WshShell = new COM(“WScript.Shell”);
    $oExec = $WshShell->Run($runCommand, 7, false);
```

Even trying JavaScript

```
function background(){
var url = "C:\wamp\www\zipfiles7.php";// No question mark needed

xmlReq=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlReq.open("POST",url,true);
xmlReq.send();
console.log("done");
}
echo '<script type="text/javascript">', 'background();', '</script>';
```

or

```
function background(){
var str = "Success";
var url = "C:\wamp\www\zipfiles7.php";

xmlReq=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlReq.open("POST",url,true);
xmlReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlReq.setRequestHeader("Content-length", str.length);
xmlReq.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlReq.send();
console.log("done");
}
```

Even Ajax isn't going to the background!

```
function background()
{
$.ajax(
    {
           type: "POST",
           url: "zipfiles7.php",
           data: data, // data to send to above script page if any
           cache: false,

           success: function(response)
           {
                alert('Succes');
           }
     });
}
```

Please help me understand why the process will not go to the background. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you call exec php halts execution of the current script until it gets a return value from the shell (from exec). So in this case, php won't continue executing the script until the file is finished being zipped.

[From the php exec() documentation page:](http://php.net/function.exec)

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to
>   continue running in the background, the output of the program must be
>   redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will
>   cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

As far as implementing this the correct way, I actually have never had to do this myself so I can't say exactly, but I hope this points you in the right direction.

Edit: [Upon searching a little further I found this stackoverflow answer which seems like it applies to your current question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13648608/2171102)

Comment: I did try redirecting the output to a file, but it still hangs. I've heard mixed reviews about using exec with windows. Some say it doesn't work at all, and some disagree. But none of the methods I am trying are working(with the hanging issue).

Comment: Then I'm not too certain what is causing the issue. If you have access to a linux development enviorment you could see if your script executes correctly in a linux enviorment? (or if you don't you could download some linux distro and set one up)

Comment: I will look into testing in a linux environment. And I do not have access, so thank you for the suggestion of setting up my own. I did try the `exec(sprintf('/usr/bin/php...` method as well without success.